# How would I get only the numbers from excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How would I extract all the numbers from a cell, so for example A1 cell contains: "AA59" I would like the formula to extract 59 and ignore AA. I can use =if(right(A1),2) formula but if A1 contains value AA5 then it will select last two characters (which is A5), so this is wrong?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771802/extract-number-from-string-in-vba/28772596#28772596) recently submitted *regular expression* solution to a similar problem.

Comment: @Jeeped Also is there a way I can use a if function to check if last 2 characters in a cell are numbers if yes i would like the function to place 0 else 1?

Comment: Something like `=IF(ISNUMBER(--RIGHT(A1, 2)), ..., ...)` would seem appropriate for that situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a native worksheet formula solution. It's a little inelegant compared to a VBA user-defined-function, but is a standard (non-array) formula and looks more complex than it actually is.

[image: Find first number in string]

The formula in B21 is,

```
=MID(A1, MIN(INDEX(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))+((CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<48)+(CODE(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))>57))*1E+99,,)), 99)
```

Fill down as necessary. Wrap the whole thing in a `VALUE(...)` function or precede `MID` with a double unary (aka *double minus* or --) to convert the text to a true number.

Comment: is there any way I can use a similar formula to get letters only so from A1 the formula should get 4A's (AAAA)?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, consider the *Array Formula*:

```
=--MID(SUMPRODUCT(--MID("01"&A1,SMALL((ROW($1:$300)-1)*ISNUMBER(-MID("01"&A1,ROW($1:$300),1)),ROW($1:$300))+1,1),10^(300-ROW($1:$300))),2,300)
```

to extract digits from a mixed cell:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

If you are always trying to get a single or double digit number from the end of the string try this version:

`=LOOKUP(100,RIGHT(A2,{1,2})+0)`

Answer (score 0):

try this macro

```
Function RakamCikart(Txt As String) As String
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
.Global = True
.Pattern = "[0-9]"
RakamCikart = .Replace(Txt, "")
End With
End Function
```