# How can i work with this poorly formatted report to create a usable table?

Tags: excel, vba, module, scripting

EDIT: 8/7/20 14:49 CLOSE THIS PLEASE
Appears its as simple as using power query to create a table from the data and filling down. I appreciate everyone taking their time to comment.

EDIT: 8/7/20 14:03
Link to File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qkk7lyf6cmimb64/uploadSched.xlsb?dl=0

I have a very poorly designed report that i am finding near impossible to work with.

[Poorly Designed Agent Schedule Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdjmV.png)

I need to use this report as i cannot query the server directly due to permission restrictions.

I need to take all the data in this report to create a table that appears as such

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPVZu.png)

I have one macro that i wrote to find all unique agents and the range where their data exists

[Agent Ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0mN4.png)

The information is forever changing based on data i need for reporting but the one consistent thing is the columns in which the data resides. I can email a copy of the file for testing purposes all Personally Identifiable Information has been scrubbed from the file.

My thoughts were that i would have to create the unique ranges as i did, then find the unique dates for each agent in the same manner on a new sheet, and then find the unique scheduled activity for each unique date on another sheet. I cant work through the logic properly it seems without creating an insane amount of work.

I am looking for direction and script examples on how to cleanly do this, i am not wanting you to do it for me (unless you have a simple way of doing it that i am completely over looking). Any and all help is appreciated, and i thank you for reviewing this question.

Comment: If you have code it's best to include it in your post - folks here are much less likely to help  if there's nothing to build from. Questions with no code tend to get closed fairly quickly, but if you add code they can be reopened.  Also, if you have a file to share, and it has no PII or other sensitive info, then posting a link to it would be better than asking for emails.

Comment: Appreciate you, thank you. https://www.dropbox.com/s/qkk7lyf6cmimb64/uploadSched.xlsb?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your AgentRange sheet is called "AgentRange" and the Desired Results sheet is called "Desired Results" then please try the following code...

```
Sub CrappyScheduleData()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim lastRow As Long, cl As Object, arr As Variant, x As Long, rowNum As Long, cl2 As Object, AgentID As String, strCells As String
ReDim arr(0, 5)
x = -1
With Sheets("CrappyScheduleData")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cl In .Range("I13:I" & lastRow)
        If cl.Value <> "" Then
            x = x + 1
            rowNum = cl.Row
            With Sheets("AgentRange")
                lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
                For Each cl2 In .Range("C2:C" & lastRow)
                    If rowNum <= cl2.Value Then
                        AgentID = GetNumbers(cl2.Offset(0, -2).Value, 0)
                    End If
                Next cl2
            End With
            arr(0, x) = AgentID
            arr(0, x + 1) = "PII Scrubbed"
            arr(0, x + 2) = Date
            arr(0, x + 3) = cl.Value
            arr(0, x + 4) = cl.Offset(0, 2).Value
            arr(0, x + 5) = cl.Offset(0, 4).Value
        With Sheets("Desired Results")
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            strCells = "A" & lastRow & ":F" & lastRow
            .Range(strCells).Value = arr
        End With
        x = -1
        End If
    Next cl
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Function GetNumbers(str As String, Occur As Long) As Long 'GOT THIS FROM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771802/extract-number-from-string-in-vba
Dim regex As Object: Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.RegExp")
regex.Pattern = "(\d+)"
regex.Global = True
Set matches = regex.Execute(str)
GetNumbers = matches(Occur)
End Function
```

In columns E and F in "Desired Results", please format the columns to Custom "h:mm AM/PM"
[image]

Comment: It is definitely close, all dates became todays date, easy enough to tweak. The get numbers function did not work on this version of excel im on right now, will try another. if you would like to see the file its self for a clearer picture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qkk7lyf6cmimb64/uploadSched.xlsb?dl=0. The excel versions are going to vary pending users role in company, anywhere from office 2013 to 365 so compatibile is required.

Comment: I only put Date so it will only put todays date... and what error did you get after trying?

Comment: Are you or your users on a Mac?

Comment: None of the users will be on a Mac, erorr: Invalid Call or Procedure on the 'Getnumbers = matches(occur)' line

Comment: Needs a check for `matches.count>0`