# store numbers out of a text in an array using VBA macros and test it

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following cell contents as an example in an Excel worksheet:

```
    commerce 81
    commerce81
    commerce1981
    commerce 1981
    law 2000
    law2000
    law00
    law 00
```

I was looking for VBA code to store only numbers out of these texts in an array which I could do and figure it out using following code:

```
Function albilynumer(cell As String) As Long
   Dim c As Long
   For c = 1 To Len(cell)
      If IsNumeric(Mid(cell, c, 1)) Then albilynumer = albilynumer & Mid(cell, c, 1)
   Next
End Function
```

But after separating number from text I want to test each to give me following result for previous example:

```
    1981
    1981
    1981
    1981
    2000
    2000
    2000
    2000
```

If any one has a clue for this I would be grateful to them.

Comment: Not clear what the problem/question is, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28772042/1188513) looks like it should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One soulution is to do it with Power Query. I started with the following table named `tblText`.

[image]

I used this table as input for Power Query (*Goto Data/From Table Range*).First step is to split the column by Non-Digit to Digit (*Goto Home/Split ColumnBy Non-Digit to Digit*)
[image]
Second and third step is to clean the result with *Goto Transform/Text Column/Format/Trim and then Clean* (no pictures for these steps). The important step is to add a column where you do the trick (*Goto Add Column*) and add the following M-formula

```
if Text.Length([Digits]) = 2 and Number.FromText([Digits]) >  51  then 
    "19" & [Digits] else if Text.Length([Digits]) = 2 and 
    Number.FromText([Digits])>= 0 then "20" & [Digits] else [Digits]
```

[image]

The result is

[image]

In a last step you remove the column digits and rename the other columns and load the result to your worksheet.

Final result could look like that

[image]

Comment: Would also work with "New column from example", I think. I swear, I literally *cried* when I first saw that feature. So awesome! PowerQuery is an excellent tool for this, +1

Comment: Thanks and ohh, okay I need to test "New column from example".

Comment: I'll Try this also but i got it with a helper collection vba code wait i'll paster it here

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be to "improve" your function. If I got you right then this give you what you are after. The logic is just the same as in the Power Query formula and one could possibly improve the `if` conditions with `select case` but I leave that to you

```
Option Explicit

Function albilynumer(cell As String) As Long
   
    Dim c As Long
    Dim res As String
    For c = 1 To Len(cell)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(cell, c, 1)) Then res = res & Mid(cell, c, 1)
    Next
   
    If Len(res) = 2 Then
        If res > 51 Then
            res = "19" & res
        Else
            If res >= 0 Then
                res = "20" & res
            End If
        End If
    End If
       
    albilynumer = CLng(res)
   
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

RegEx is a cleaner solution here. No looping in VBA:

```
Function ParseNum$(cell$)
    Dim n&
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "\d+"
        If .Test(cell) Then
            n = .Execute(cell)(0)
            If n < 100 Then If n > 51 Then n = n + 1900 Else n = n + 2000
            ParseNum = n
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

---

Then simply call as a worksheet function:

```
=ParseNum(A2)
```

---

And here is how to populate an array, using the above function:

```
Sub ArrayResult()
    Dim i&, v
    v = [a2:a11]
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        v(i, 1) = ParseNum(CStr(v(i, 1)))
    Next
    [b2:b11] = v
End Sub
```

---

The result:

[image]