# Get only numeric values in VBA

Tags: vba

I have a string

```
Dim A As String
A = "A23"
B = "bd4"
```

I need to get only the numeric values as the output as below

```
A = 23
B = 4
```

Comment: There are some excellent answer to that questions over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771802/extract-number-from-string-in-vba

Comment: I'm unable to undelete the question

Comment: Im asking new question

Comment: @jezrael I asked new question You can answer there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex replacement here:

```
Dim A As String: A = "A23"
Dim AOut As String
Dim pattern As String: pattern = "\D+"
Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

With regEx
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = pattern
End With

AOut = regEx.Replace(A, "")
Debug.Print AOut
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim A As String
A = "bd4"
number_val = Range(A).Row
MsgBox (number_val)
```

We can use range function, this gives the numeric from the string.

Comment: This workaround is restricted to the current columns.count (16384 columns), i.e. to a limited character combination ranging from (column) A:XFD. Reading the original question it's not evident that possibly you assume only (valid) **range addresses** as inputs, and no other non-digit character combinations :-;